# Error FullCalendar JS - TypeError: s.computeEventDraggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, fullcalendar

Este es el error que me muestra la consola de Chrome

```
Uncaught TypeError: s.computeEventDraggable is not a function
at r.renderSegHtml (main.min.js:6)
at r.e.renderSegEls (main.min.js:9)
at r.e.renderSegs (main.min.js:9)
at i [as renderFgEvents] (main.min.js:6)
at i.render (main.min.js:6)
at i.e.receiveProps (main.min.js:8)
at r.render (main.min.js:6)
at r.e.receiveProps (main.min.js:8)
at i.render (main.min.js:6)
at i.e.receiveProps (main.min.js:8)
```

Estoy cargando los eventos desde un Json que se almacena en el localstorage, este es el código que estoy utilizando para mostrar el Calendario el error ocurre cuando se ejecuta **calendar.render();**

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('CalendarioClase');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl,{
    header:{
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    progressiveEventRendering: true,
    defaultView: 'timeGridDay',
    locale: 'es',
    plugins: [ 'bootstrap', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
    timeZone: 'America/Bogota',
    events: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("clases")),
    eventClick: function(info){
        //Eventos cuando se hace clic
    },
    eventRender: function(info){
        $(info.el).popover({
            container: "body",
            content: info.event.extendedProps.contenido,
            html: true,
            placement: 'top',
            template: "<div class='popover' role='tooltip'><div class='arrow'></div><h3 class='popover-header'></h3><div class='popover-body'></div></div>",
            title: info.event.title,
            trigger: 'hover'
        });
    }
});
calendar.render();
```

Funciono bien hasta el día de ayer.

Alguno sabe que puede estar pasando o como soluciono el problema, estoy usando la ultima version de FullCalendar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just change JS versions in the javascript files you include to:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@4.3.1/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.3.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@4/locales-all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.3.0/main.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Eso fue el cambio que realice, cambie los CDN a la ultima version y todo volvió a funcionar perfectamente.